Formbuilder: How to fill an email address field when passed via the FORM URL (i.e. clicked on link with email address set)?
New to Formbuilder, working on a "I want to Volunteer" form.
When we send out emails about volunteering for our organisation in the email I want to attach the email address to the LINK of the (formbuilder) VOLUNTEER form so the email address can be filled automatically - simply to reduce errors.
I tried to find the answers but the documentation is a little sparse about this.
How can I do this?
Please help!

If you wish to prefill a field like email from the url, you can do so by constructing a link like this:
https://example.org/civicrm/my-form#/?email=youremail@example.com
Note the hash-slash-questionmark syntax which passes the variables to javascript rather than php.
To pass more than one field value, separate it with an & like
https://example.org/civicrm/my-form#/?first_name=Jane&last_name=Doe

Thanks, that works!
Does this work for other fields, e.g. firstname?
I have already created a 'backup' using jquery, document.ready and document.on(ajaxcomplete) - this works, too, I can add email/fname/lname.

Yes, updated my answer to show how it works with multiple fields. No need for jQuery.

Is there a list of parameters somewhere? Why I am asking is it seems not related to the ACTUAL id/name of the field - I tried this with the actual ID before you answered this and it did not work.

It sounds like you need an authentication token.
In FormBuilder, you can create tokens that identify a contact and pre-fill the form for them. You'll find this feature in the "Placement" dropdown when configuring your form. Once selected, save your form and then the token will be available for you in CiviMail.

Thanks, but that requires a send from within CIVICRM.
They are NOT in the DB yet, the email is send from Mailchimp/Omnisend.

Perhaps this recipe will help?
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4462#note_172996

I think this falls into the same category as @Coleman explained.
While I can see this to be useful when sending emails from within CIVIRM this does not help me if it some from a different mailer.

ok.  i don't think that was clear in the Question. I +1 coleman's second answer. only risk of course is that with the email exposed folk could potentially mess with it (but why would they)
